# TranslateAnimation in android doesnt work well

Tags: android, animation

I am trying to write a function that moves the view "who" from "from" to "to". But it doesn't work in some cases and in others it just starts and finishes in wrong positions. What did I do wrong by my using of this animation type?

```
  private void moveFromToShow(View from, View to, View who, boolean repeat) {
    t = new TranslateAnimation(from.getX(), to.getX(), from.getY(), to.getY());
    if(repeat){
        t.setRepeatMode(TranslateAnimation.INFINITE);
        t.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);
        t.setRepeatMode(TranslateAnimation.RESTART);
    }
    t.setDuration(3000);
    t.setFillAfter(true);
    t.setZAdjustment(TranslateAnimation.ZORDER_TOP);
    who.bringToFront();         
    who.startAnimation(t);
    currentFreeAnimIndx++;
}
```

edit-explantion:

For example I have 2 views and want the image that is inside one of them to move to the other view. I send moveFromToShow(view1, view2, view1.getChildrenAt(0)); and I get the animation from near to view1(but not even exactly it) moving to outside of the screen.

I wanted this function to be universal for moving view from one to other  view.

Comment: You need to be a lot more specific-  we don't see this animation, and we aren't psychic.  What is it you want/expect, and what is it you actually see?

Comment: For example I have 2 views and want the image that is inside one of them to move to the other view. I send moveFromToShow(view1, view2, view1.getChildrenAt(0)); and I get the animation from near to view1 moving to outside of the screen. I wanted this function to be universal for moving view from one to other.

Comment: getX and getY return X and y position relative to the parent.  Unless view1, view2, and who are all in the same layout (meaning they all have the exact same parent) then they have different coordinate systems and using those functions won't work.  This is probably part of the problem.

Comment: So how can I implement an universal function for moving views like that?

Comment: Use the 8 parameter constructor and use screen coordinates with the ABSOLUTE coordinate types to the animation.  Use getLocationOnScreen to get the absolute positions of each view, rather than getX and getY

Comment: I tried : int[] locationFrom = new int[2];
  int[] locationTo = new int[2];
  from.getLocationOnScreen(locationFrom);
  to.getLocationOnScreen(locationTo);
  
  t=new TranslateAnimation(Animation.ABSOLUTE, locationFrom[0],
    Animation.ABSOLUTE, locationTo[0], Animation.ABSOLUTE, locationFrom[1], Animation.ABSOLUTE, locationTo[1]);

Comment: but still happens and moving from unrelated place to other.. are there other parameters that can cause this?